# How to generate a full dynamic grid with Linq and JQuery DataTable?

Tags: jquery, .net, linq, datatables

its my first time here so, take it easy please.

I'm `using C#/ASP.NET` Web Formss approch to develop the web-site. 
The code below is populating a `gridView`, so, i would like to use this same return to populate the `DataTable`, maybe using `Repeater`.

#### Declaring delegate

```
public delegate object ListMethod
public ListMethod listMethod;
```

#### Defining the listMethod

```
(Page.Master as Gestao).listMethod = listaTodos;
```

#### the listaTodos method

```
return usrMethods.Listar().ToList(); // Which returns a List<T>
```

#### Populating the GridView

```
if (!listMethod.Equals(null))
{
    this.ListagemView.DataSource = listMethod();
    this.ListagemView.DataBind();
}
```

Well, if you guys need more information, tell me about.

Most examples using `Repeater` & `dataTables`, needs to define the `Columns` manually in the `<HeaderTemplate>`, and then defining the same amount of `<tr>` in the `<ItemTemplate>`. The problem, in my case, is that i don't know the amout of columns in the list, neither their names.

Thank you in advice,
and really sorry for bad english.

Comment: just set AutoGeneralColumns=true, is not ok for you?

Comment: @Tim.Tang, actually, my problems don't rely on using the GridView, but the dataTables JQuery Plugin. The main problem is the dataTable needs you to specify the columns amount and columns name, that, in my case i don't know. See more about the dataTables [here](http://www.datatables.net) Thank you.

Comment: Please use the “add comment” button in the comment section below questions and answers to comment on answers or reply to comments on your question. Stack Overflow isn’t a forum, and the answers section is for answers to the question at hand only. Thanks :)

Comment: @minitech, thank you. Actually, in my company we use a proxy, so, we are unable to see 'javascript' code, thats why i wasn't seeing and using the comment. Thanks for the convert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DataTables *requires* a proper table layout. If you're using ASP.NET Gridviews, it does not render the table header in a `thead` tag with `th` elements... it uses a css-styled row in the `tbody` to look like a table header. DataTables doesn't know what to do with this.

There is a workaround. Create this method:

```
void gridview_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  var gv = (GridView)sender;
  if (gv.HeaderRow != null) {
    gv.HeaderRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader;
  }
}
```

Then in your codeblock:

```
if (!listMethod.Equals(null))
{
  this.ListagemView.DataBound += gridview_DataBound; // <--- ADD THIS LINE
  this.ListagemView.DataSource = listMethod();
  this.ListagemView.DataBind();
}
```

Then in your JavaScript you should just be able to call:

```
$('#<%= this.ListagemView.ClientID %>').dataTable();
```

Shouldn't need any columns explicitly defined because DataTables will auto-detect from the `thead` which is now being generated properly.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I'm not yet a pro on javascript/jquery usage, and so, as long as i'm away from my Laptop at this moment, i couldn't understand whats you mean by using `.ClientID`. Is this attribute used to store HeaderColumns values? BTW, thank you one more time, i really appreciate the approach!

Comment: actually i'm starting the project, so, i'm able to choose the jquery or grid to use on it. Do you recommend me using datatables to manipulate the grid? thank you.

Comment: I would definitely recommend DataTables. I use it almost daily, and it's very fast and reasonably flexible. There are a few things in the current 1.9.x version which I have to work around, but it's nothing major. Really depends on your application though...it's overkill if all you need is basic sorting or something like that.

Comment: thank you one more time for your incredible help. Worked just fine. BUT, "there is allays a 'but'", im using this with master page, and, when i try to apply the dataTable() to the gridViews clientID, it actually dosen't working. Do you know if there is a problem using jquery/dataTable with masterPage? The gridview is out of the contentplaceholder, so, he is default, changing only the data thats showed. Any concerns? thank you in advice =)

Comment: again, thank you. I managed to solve the issue by changing <script src="../FuncoesCliente/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script> for <script src="<%= Page.ResolveUrl("~/FuncoesCliente/jquery.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script> wich works just pretty well =) thank you all. Problems solved!